# Render total page count in document.xml of .docx file

Tags: xml, ms-word, docx

I had following code to render total page number in *word/document.xml* of my *.docx* file.

```
<w:r w:rsidR="004D2840"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="24"/><w:szCs w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
<w:r w:rsidR="00005B3E">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
  <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">NUMPAGES</w:instrText>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
```

But for newer versions of Word (version 16.16 180812) this code is not working. What I've tried:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="004D2840">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
<w:r w:rsidR="00005B3E">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:fldChar w:dirty="true" w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00005B3E">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:instrText>NUMPAGES</w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00005B3E">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00DB7413">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:noProof/>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>28</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00005B3E">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
```

Also as you can see I used `w:dirty="true"` along with `w:fldCharType="begin"` and on opening *.docx* file it ask me if I want to update fields in document I answer yes and it updates always to 1.

Also founded this tag `<w:pgNum />` which insert current page number but didn't found same tag for total page number.

Is there any way to render total page number in Word 16.16?
Thanks!

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing is a problem with how the Office build you're opening the document with is rendering the field code - that it's a problem (bug) in the Word application, not with the way you're creating the document. I vaguely recall seeing something about this cropping up (again - it was a problem in an earlier version of Word for a while). Two things: 1) Test inserting the NumPages as an end-user, save, close, re-open the document and check if there's the same problem; 2) Look around / ask around in some end-user forums if this build of Word is having this problem, generally.

Comment: ...and if you do ask in an end-user forum be sure to mention not only the version and build number but also where in the document the field is located (header, footer, document body...) as that can make a difference how/when the field updates.

Comment: @CindyMeister The thing is that this _.docx_ file is generated automatically. If I'll click with right mouse button and choose update field it would be updated properly.

Comment: @CindyMeister And this code in body of a document.

Comment: Field codes in the document body behave differently than in the header/footer. It's possible that the field code update in this scenario is happening before the document has finished paginating. Can you test putting the field code in a header or footer as well as in the document body and see if the one in the header or footer updates correctly? FWIW if it is a case of the document not having paginated when the prompt is clicked I don't think there's anything you can do about it short of instructing the user or at least making sure the option to "Update fields" when the document prints is "on".

Comment: @CindyMeister I tried in footer and it was ok. Also I tried with "Update fields" in settings.xml and the total page count in body was still 1.